# Passing <List> filter values to an action component (REACTADMIN)

Tags: react-admin

How can I get the filter values of my ReactAdmin  Element ? 
I can get the size of the List, but I don't know how to get the filter, that I can pass to my custom action component:

**in my App.tsx:**

```
const MyActions = ({
    total,
    filters,
    filterValues,
    ...rest
}) => (
    <MyButton listsize={total} filters={filters} filterValues={filterValues} />
);

export const MyFilter = (props) => (
    <Filter {...props}>
        <TextInput label="Search" source="q" alwaysOn/>
    </Filter>
);


<List {...props} actions={<MyActions {...props}/>} title="My List" perPage={25} filters={<MyFilter/>}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
            <TextField source="id"/>
            <TextField source="name"/>
            <TextField source="info"/>
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

**My Action Button Component;**

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
    console.log('this.props.listsize : ' + JSON.stringify(this.props.listsize));
    console.log('this.props.filters : ' + this.props.filters);
console.log('this.props.filterValues.q : ' + this.props.filterValues.q);
        return (
            <anyContent...>
        )
    }
}
```

The Console Output is just:

```
this.props.listsize : 145 (Size is correct) 

this.props.filters : [object Object]

this.props.filters.filterValues.q : undefined
```

How can I fetch the current filter for the  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter value can be obtained from the property: `filterValues: {q: "test"}`
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#empty-page

Comment: Thanks for helping. Still habe problems reading the filter. I have added filterValues to the props and try to read the q value, but still it is undefined. Could you please look into my updated code again ?

Comment: Correct option: this.props.filterValues, there are more: this.props.displayedFilters, this.props.showFilter, 
is it possible that the 'q' filter field was not filled in?